# How can I iterate through xml and remove the duplicates? C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've created a program to retrieve data from a database and convert it to XML. It returns a list of 24 objects that I created:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-16"
<ArrayOfData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Data>
        <interval>01</interval>
        <num>12345</num>
        <id>ABC123 </id>
        <type>LETTER</type>
        <party>1</party>
        <amount>-10</amount>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <interval>02</interval>
        <num>12345</num>
        <id>ABC123 </id>
        <type>LETTER</type>
        <party>1</party>
        <amount>-11</amount>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <interval>03</interval>
        <num>12345</num>
        <id>ABC123 </id>
        <type>LETTER</type>
        <party>1</party>
        <amount>-12</amount>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <interval>04</interval>
        <num>12345</num>
        <id>ABC123 </id>
        <type>LETTER</type>
        <party>1</party>
        <amount>-13</amount>
    </Data>
```

Basically the data goes on with incrementing intervals by 1 up to 24.
What I am looking for is to look for what is duplicate and just concatenate them into one child, and then to look for what differs and create a different element for it but keep them everything in one child. How can I write the XML to do this? Example:

```
 <Data>
    <num>12345</num>
    <id>ABC123 </id>
    <type>LETTER</type>
    <party>1</party>
    <details>
        <interval>01</interval>
        <amount>-10</amount>
    </details>
    <details>
        <interval>02</interval>
        <amount>-11</amount>
    </details>
    <details>
        <interval>03</interval>
        <amount>-12</amount>
    </details>
    <details>
        <interval>04</interval>
        <amount>-13</amount>
    </details>
</Data>
```

I want to create a function that returns this XML. The parameters in my current function now are just there to get the data using those parameters. Here's how I generate the XML now:

```
     public IActionResult CreateXML(int num, int id)
            {
                string xml = "";
                var temp = (from x in Context.InternalData.AsNoTracking() where (x.num == num && x.id == id) select x).ToList();
                using (var stringwrite = new Utf8StringWriter())
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(temp.GetType());
                    serializer.Serialize(stringwrite, temp);
                    xml = stringwrite.ToString();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringwriter.ToString());
                reader.ReadLine();  //skips the UTF-16 header

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                XElement arrayOfData = doc.Root;
                List<XElement> newData = new List<XElement>();

                var parties = doc.Descendants("Data")
                    .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("id"))
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var party in parties)
                {
                    XElement template = party.First();

                    List<XElement> details = party.Select(x => new XElement("details", new object[] {
                        new XElement("interval", (string)x.Element("interval")),
                        new XElement("amount", (string)x.Element("amount"))
                    })).ToList();

                    template.Element("interval").Remove();
                    template.Element("amount").Remove();
                    template.Add(details);
                    newData.Add(template);
                }
                arrayOfData.ReplaceAll(newData);
                return Ok(arrayOfData);

            }

                }
```

I am new to this and have never worked with generating XML before. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post part of the code that generates this xml so we have an understanding on how you do this

Comment: Sorry, edited @sommmen

Comment: You xml has lots of errors.  Please fix.  You can validate the xml in VS using following menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste the xml into the view.  Error will show up like compiler errors in the Error View.

Comment: it's been fixed, thanks! @jdweng

Comment: First, you have a collection of data - `IEnumerable<Data> temp` - that's what you need to work with, without creating an intermediate xml. Second, you are using both `XmlDocument` and `XmlSerializer` for some reason. This is an extra cost of both memory and processor. Third, you return a `string`. You either need to work with xml immediately, or write it directly to the output stream (response)... In general, everything is inefficient.

Comment: This is my first time attempting something like this, do you have any tips? Basically need to use this to return XML.

Comment: I edited and posted my new function, do you have any additional insight? @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: You have two string writers.  Just take the output of your first writer and put into my string reader so you can remove the 1st line.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for all of your help, output is as desired!

Comment: Also, how can I handle the event where there should be only 24 intervals, however in the case that there are 2 pieces of data that will have the same NUM, what will be returned is the NUM with 48 intervals. How can I split this into 2 different NUMS? Each with 24 intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
            stringwriter.Write(xml);

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringwriter.ToString());
            reader.ReadLine();  //skips the UTF-16 header

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            XElement arrayOfData = doc.Root;
            List<XElement> newData = new List<XElement>();

            var parties = doc.Descendants("Data")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("id"))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var party in parties)
            {
                XElement template = party.First();

                List<XElement> details = party.Select(x => new XElement("details", new object[] {
                    new XElement("interval", (string)x.Element("interval")),
                    new XElement("amount", (string)x.Element("amount"))
                })).ToList();

                template.Element("interval").Remove();
                template.Element("amount").Remove();
                template.Add(details);
                newData.Add(template);
            }
            arrayOfData.ReplaceAll(newData);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212827/discussion-on-answer-by-jdweng-how-can-i-iterate-through-xml-and-remove-the-dupl).